# Add a class to a cell depending on data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable

```
<table data-bind="dataTable: { 
        data: items, 
        options: {
            bPaginate: false,
            aaSorting: [[0, 'desc']],
            aoColumns: [ 
                { sClass: 'date', mDataProp: 'date' }, 
                { mDataProp: 'time' }, 
                { sClass: 'name', mDataProp: 'name' }, 
                { sClass: 'thought', mDataProp: 'thought' } 
            ] 
        } 
    }">
```

there is also another value in the items that I don't display (thought type).
I want to change the class of the cell 'thought' depending on the value of 'thought type'.

So if thought type is new idea I want the cell that displays the value of 'thought' to be yellow.

Is this possible with datatables?

Comment: @FaceOfJock: This is JavaScript, using the jQuery DataTables plugin.

Comment: thanks , i just see this link about it http://datatables.net/download/

Comment: Give us the equivalent html output , it will be more easier for those who don't know this plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function

```
"fnRender": function(obj) {
                    var sReturn = obj.aData[ obj.iDataColumn ];
                    if ( sReturn == "is wat you needed" ) {
                        sReturn = "add style to your element";
                    }
                    return sReturn;
                }
```

Go through the example shown in below link

http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

You can see that the A alphabet is bold compared to others..Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thank you a million times over

Comment: Where is the example on http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html ?

Answer (score 1):

This Solution help fix my problem might help u. 
for more info check this link: [columns.createdCell](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell)

Using **createdCell** manipulate the DOM within columnDefs options.

For example,

```
"columnDefs": [ 
{
   "targets": [1] // first CELL That will be checked,
   "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
             if (cellData < 1) {
                 $(td).addClass('someClass');
              }
    }
 },{
   "targets": [2] //second CELL That will be checked,
   "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
             if (cellData < 1) {
                 $(td).addClass('someClass');
              }
    }
 }  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [at `fnRowCallback` in the API](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks).  For any given row, this can respond to that row just after drawing it and adjust the row as needed based on the data of that row.  For example, something like this might work:

```
'fnRowCallback' : function(row, data) {
    if (data[0] === 'someValue') {
        $('td:eq(0)', row).addClass('someClass');
    }
}
```